# list files sorting when the input have the same name

Tags: r

Sorry if my question is very simple for you but I could not save it because I am new in this language. 
I have many files which all are called Sample1 to sample300

I tried to load them all by different ways

```
file <- list.files("path to data", pattern="*sample")
```

Then I also set the `full.names=TRUE`
I also did

```
files <- sort(file)
```

I read this one [How can I read the files in a directory in sorted order using R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777367/how-can-i-read-the-files-in-a-directory-in-sorted-order-using-r) and [Why R order files as 1 10 100 not 1 2 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786460/why-r-order-files-as-1-10-100-not-1-2-3?noredirect=1&lq=1) but I could not understand how to do it.

The problem is that it gives my data like this

```
path to /Sample1.txt
path to /Sample10.txt
path to /Sample100.txt 
.
.
.
```

How can I make it in a way that it gives

```
path to /Sample1.txt
path to /Sample2.txt
path to /sample3.txt 
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would extract the numeric part, convert to numeric and sort:

```
library(stringr)
file_number <- as.numeric(str_extract(file, "[0-9]+"))
file <- file[order(file_number)]
```

Comment: thanks, it is great solution but if you find another way , please post